# openoffice template startup get directory macro

Tags: path, macros, openoffice-writer

I like to start a openoffice template (.ott) via my command prompt. 
Once my template.ott has opened it is called Untitled 1.odt

What I need is way to get the location of the template.ott (the path to the directory of the template that made Untitled 1.odt). I want to use that path in a macro in Untitled 1.odt

The question summarized:
So when I have a macro in Untitled 1.odt, how do I get the location of the template.ott?

I use OpenOffice Writer.

**EDIT:** I write macros in Openoffice Basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Listing 5.47 of [Andrew Pitonyak's macro document](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php):

```vb
Sub GetTemplatePath
    Dim oDocProps
    oDocProps = ThisComponent.getDocumentProperties()
    MsgBox "TemplateURL " & oDocProps.TemplateURL
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! I did not set a Name for my Template and no Title so it first seemed like it didn't work.